# Loading data with special characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to load data infile using MySQL. However in one of the files, the column contains a directory path for icons. For example, IconFile column contains **\image\icon\department\bathroom.jpg**.

However, when I import this, the field becomes **imageicondepartment?athroom.jpg**.

Current load data infile command:

```
load data local infile 'd:\\project2014\\g3t4\\data\\department.txt'
into table department
fields terminated by '\t' 
escaped by '\\' 
optionally enclosed by'"' 
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines;
```

How do you correct the load data infile command so that it imports properly?

Anyone have a solution that captures \ characters accurately? Solution must be within the SQL load data infile command, in the assignment I am not allowed to modify the txt file or use any other software.

Need a solution, not an explanation of why I am encountering this. Any help??

Comment: can you show your text file structure?

Answer (score 0):

1. you are reading from a text file and loading into a table of mysql, as the table contains columns so it will require some csv or excel formatted data to load it properly into rows and columns.
2. `\image\icon\department\bathroom.jpg` - you are using this so it will get merged into columns as you said. `imageicondepartment\bathroom.jpg` - and `\b` will change to `?` which I think may be getting treated like a special character.